# How to prevent table header from adding linefeed?

Tags: html-table

I have a table in which the tableheader contents are creating linefeed when its long...

```
<th>Accounting Date Time (hh:mm): </th>
```

What happens is that after the word Date, the rest of the title is on the second line. pls advise. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS.

```
th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Works in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html)

Comment: I didn't know I had a son, Son of Man `:P`

Comment: @Son there has been for a while. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_3